# Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds in mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to upload an image, and an getting the following exception on the third line:

```
 var file = Request.Files[0];
 var imgBytes = new Byte[file.ContentLength - 1];
 file.InputStream.Read(imgBytes, 0, file.ContentLength);
 var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imgBytes,0,imgBytes.Length);
 p.Photo = base64String;
```

Comment: That's because you're creating an array that is X-1 bytes, but reading X bytes into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code says: allocate (n - 1) bytes, read n bytes.

```
var imgBytes = new Byte[file.ContentLength]; // <- Remove - 1
file.InputStream.Read(imgBytes, 0, file.ContentLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're making a simple mistake when creating your array, and it's probably rooted in the fact that arrays are zero-based (i.e. positions start with 0).

First, to make this extremely clear, consider an array that should contain three elements, `{A, B, C}`. When you store those in an array, `A` will have the index `0`, `B` will have `1`, and `C` will be at `2`.

In other words, the last item will be at the *position* `length - 1`. The *length itself* though, will still be 3.

Apply that to your situation, and you'll realize the problem lies here:

```
 var imgBytes = new Byte[file.ContentLength - 1];
```

Remove the `-1` and it should work.

If you needed to read directly from the last byte in your array on the other hand, you'd use `file.ContentLength - 1` to access it.